# Calling function from another Javascript file and an object is said to be null

Tags: javascript, jquery

A word game source code is placed in the file Main.js.

And now I am trying to add another file, Bookmarks.js (included in the web page before the Main.js file), which would have an object `var bookmarks = {};` synchronized with local storage.

Unfortunately, when I call functions defined in Bookmarks.js from the Main.js, I get the error messages stating, that the bookmarks is null:

[image: screenshot]

Here a text copy of the error message:

```
test?player=abcde:110 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null
    at getBookmark (test?player=abcde:110)
    at updateBoard (test?player=abcde:244)
    at setSelectedGid (test?player=abcde:159)
    at rebuildMenu (test?player=abcde:197)
    at WebSocket.ws.onmessage (test?player=abcde:151)
```

Please helpe me to understand, how can it even be - since the `bookmarks` variable is set at the very top of my Bookmarks.js file:

```
'use strict';

// a map for local storage: game id -> obj with "words" and "total" properties
var bookmarks = {};

function saveBookmarks(games) {
    for (var gid in bookmarks) {
        // Javascript: skip any inherited properties
        if (!bookmarks.hasOwnProperty(gid)) {
            continue;
        }
        // if games obj does not have a property gid,
        // then remove it from bookmarks obj as well
        if (!games.hasOwnProperty(gid)) {
            delete bookmarks[gid];
        }
    }
    try {
        window.localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    }
}

function getBookmark(gid) {
    if (
        // if the bookmark for the game id is not found
        !bookmarks.hasOwnProperty(gid) ||
        !bookmarks[gid].hasOwnProperty('words') ||
        !bookmarks[gid].hasOwnProperty('total')) {
        // then return an empty object
        bookmarks[gid] = {
            words: '',
            total: 0
        };
    }

    return bookmarks[gid];
}

function updateBookmark(gid, words, total, games) {
    if (
        // if the bookmark for the game id is not found or
        !bookmarks.hasOwnProperty(gid) ||
        !bookmarks[gid].hasOwnProperty('words') ||
        !bookmarks[gid].hasOwnProperty('total') ||
        // the bookmark is found, but its total score is lower
        total > bookmarks[gid]['total']) {
        // then save a bookmark obj with new values
        bookmarks[gid] = {
            words: words,
            total: total
        };
        // and update the local storage
        saveBookmarks(games);
    }

    return bookmarks[gid];
}


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    try {
        bookmarks = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    }
});
```

Comment: From the snippet you have here I can see no reason for that TypeError to be thrown. My guess would somewhere in your Main.js file you are setting the value of bookmarks to be null.

Comment: I have checked and I do not reference `bookmarks` from Main.js. Could the reason be the line `bookmarks = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));` in the Bookmarks.js?

Comment: It can indeed be. If there are not item named 'bookmarks' in the local storage it will return null and parsing a null value to JSON will again return null. In that case, bookmarks will be null. So this means that when your script runs for the first time or when your page is refreshed, local storage is not persisting the value and therefore you get the TypeError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You override the `bookmarks` value defined at the top of the file with:

> ```
> jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
>     try {
>         bookmarks = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
>     } catch (ex) {
>         console.log(ex);
>     }
> });
> ```

`window.localStorage.getItem('bookmarks')` will return `null` if the key does not exist. Then `JSON.parse(null)` will return `null`, which is then assigned to `bookmarks`.

Make sure to use the previous value if `bookmarks` is not defined in `localStorage`:

```
bookmarks = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('bookmarks')) || bookmarks;
```